# Can you pass a prop in a map function in React?

Tags: reactjs, json

Should it be simple? One component, one .json file, multiple objects, and a prop to return one of these objects. Honestly not sure if a prop can be passed this way?

#### Card Component

Currently, this is showing the featured array just fine via `cardsData.featured.map`.

```js
import './Card.scss';
import cardsData from '../../assets/dataNew';

const Card = () => {
    return (
        <>
            {cardsData.featured.map((card, i) => {
                let cardLink = card.links.linkOne;
                return (
                    <div key={i} className="card">
                        <h1>{props.foo}</h1>
                        <div className="card__image">
                            <picture>
                                <source
                                    media="(max-width: 767px)"
                                    srcSet={card.smallImg}
                                />
                                <img src={card.largeImg} alt="" />
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card__title">{card.title}</div>
                        <div className="skills">
                            {card.skills.map((skill, i) => {
                                return <span key={i}>{skill}</span>;
                            })}
                        </div>
                        <ul className="card__links">
                            <li>
                                <a
                                    target="_blank"
                                    href={card.links.linkOne}
                                    className="underline-hover">
                                    View project
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            {cardLink && (
                                <li>
                                    <a
                                        target="_blank"
                                        href={card.links.linkTwo}
                                        className="underline-hover">
                                        View code
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            )}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
};

export default Card;
```

#### Data

The featured object has 4 items total, and the standard has 10 total but will increase over time.

```json
{
    "featured": [
        {
            "title": "Designo",
            "largeImg": "./img/thumbnail-project__14-lg.webp",
            "smallImg": "./img/thumbnail-project__14-sm.webp",
            "skills": ["SCSS", "HTML", "React.js"],
            "links": {
                "linkOne": "https://satrop.github.io/Designo/",
                "linkTwo": "https://github.com/satrop/Designo"
            }
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ],
    "standard": [
        {
            "title": "Audiophile",
            "largeImg": "./img/thumbnail-project__10-lg.webp",
            "smallImg": "./img/thumbnail-project__10-sm.webp",
            "skills": ["SCSS", "HTML", "React.js"],
            "links": {
                "linkOne": "https://satrop.github.io/audiophile/#/",
                "linkTwo": "https://github.com/satrop/audiophile"
            }
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I initially thought that I could pass a prop link this...

```js
const Card = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            {cardsData[props.category].map((card, i) => {
                ...
```

And grabbing it on the other side like this...

```html
<Cards category="featured" />
```

I just get "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')" error.

I'm not sure what to look for to get what I want.

Comment: you probably want to give that `category` value a string, not an object value. so `category='featured'`

Comment: Oops! Typing too fast for my own good! 

Switched that to a string and a different error is thrown. "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

Comment: I updated the OG post to reflect that update, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `categories` != `category`

Comment: Urg! I need to have a lot more coffee today. Updated that but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an oversimplified sandbox using your example

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-shtern-lgjiv6?file=/components/card.jsx)

It seems to work just fine. You can also set `"standard"` in `App.js` and verify that the page updates.

Can you see any difference to your local code?

Comment: There it is! I forgot to add the ```?```

```js
{cardsData[category].map((card, i) => {
```

Comment: Yeah, folded that in and it works fine. Typical cant see the wood through the forest.

Thank you for making that simple example! I used that to compare and the question mark jumped right out at me.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to render the Card component when mapping the data.

```
//get the data coming from App(Parent) as a props(destructuring)
function Card({title, smallImg, largeImg, skill, links}) {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="card">
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <div className="card__image">
                    <picture>
                        <source
                            media="(max-width: 767px)"
                            srcSet={smallImg}
                        />
                        <img src={largeImg} alt="" />
                    </picture>
                </div>
                <div className="card__title">{title}</div>
                <div className="skills">
//never use the index as key because can cause flickering when manipulate the array
                    {skill.map((skill, i) => {
                        return <span key={skill}>{skill}</span>;
                    })}
                </div>
                <ul className="card__links">
                    <li>
                        <a
                            target="_blank"
//when work with object is recomended to use obj?.wherever to void crash if the key does exist
                            href={links?.linkOne}
                            className="underline-hover">
                            View project
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {links?.linkTwo && (
                        <li>
                            <a
                                target="_blank"
                                href={links.linkTwo}
                                className="underline-hover">
                                View code
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default function App() {
    const cardData = [
        {
            title: 'card 1',
            smallImg: '../src/bg_4_colors.png',
            largeImg: '../src/bg_4_colors.png',
            links: {
                linkOne: "https://satrop.github.io/audiophile/#/",
                linkTwo: "https://github.com/satrop/audiophile"
            },
            skills: ['skill_1', 'skill_2', "skill_3"]
        },
        {
            title: 'card 2',
            smallImg: '../src/bg_4_colors.png',
            largeImg: '../src/bg_4_colors.png',
            links: {
                linkOne: "https://satrop.github.io/audiophile/#/",
                linkTwo: "https://github.com/satrop/audiophile"
            },
            skills: ['skill_1', 'skill_2', "skill_3"]
        }
    ]
    return (
        <div>
            {cardData.map(item =>
                <Card
                    key={item.title}
                    title={item.title}
                    smallImg={item.smallImg}
                    largeImg={item.largeImg}
                    links={item.links}
                    skill={item.skills}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```